# Monitoring Flowground

Tags: flowground

This question goes directly to the [Flowground](https://flowground.net/) developers: Error notifications can currently only be sent by e-mail. This is very difficult to integrate into a monitoring system.

I know that I can use the API to query whether a flow is currently running or not. But I can not receive any error messages.

In the original API of elastic.io it is also possible to access logs: https://api.elastic.io/docs/v2/#retrieve-all-workspace-logs This does not work with Flowground. Are there plans or other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is currently "experimental" on the elastic.io instance. As soon as it will be productive, it will also be available on flowground.net.

Nonetheless I will talk with elastic.io, if it will be possible, to get access to this "experimental" feature a little bit earlier and give you feedback @Stephan Häußler.

Comment: It is part of our next release, that we plan to launch at the end of February @Stephan Häußler.